# How to parse the xml lines without field names in it using golang

Tags: xml, go, parsing, struct, xml-parsing

I am facing difficulty in parsing the xml lines as shown below in using golang.
Here i need to include all the attributes too for parsing.
please help me with this

my sample xml is

```
<vmap:data content="kid" cartoon="Popeye" id="1">
    <vmap:url status="found">
        <link>www.liink.com</link> 
    </vmap:url>
</vmap:data>
```

what will be the struct format of this parsing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/) tool.

In your case the result is:

```
type Data struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"data"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Content string   `xml:"content,attr"`
    Cartoon string   `xml:"cartoon,attr"`
    ID      string   `xml:"id,attr"`
    URL     struct {
        Text   string `xml:",chardata"`
        Status string `xml:"status,attr"`
        Link   string `xml:"link"`
    } `xml:"url"`
}
```